# Buffer Overflow Exception during evaluation process GraalVM

Tags: java, rust, llvm, graalvm, polyglot

I am trying to execute a rust function in java using GraalVMs polyglot llvm features, however It is throwing a buffer overflow exception.

I compiled a rust library into a llvm bytecode file for use with GraalVM Java. However, when I try evaluating this file using Graalvms polyglot features, it returns a Overflow exception during evaluation of this file. I want to be able to execute any function from this llvm source file.

Here is my process:

Compiling the rust project -
`cargo rustc --release -- --emit=llvm-bc` (crate type cdylib, includes 6 dependencies)

The java function utilizing the rust llvm code:

```java
/* imports and class declaration not shown */
void runFunctionFromLLVM() {
    try {
        Context polyglot = Context.newBuilder().allowNativeAccess(true).build();
        // accesses the rust llvm library
        File file = new File("(projectpath)/src/backend/target/release/deps/backend.bc");

        Source source = Source.newBuilder("llvm", file).build();

        // Buffer overflow traced to this function
        Value cpart = polyglot.eval(source);

        // attempts to access a function, but cannot due to the previous buffer overflow
        System.out.println(cpart.getMember("logTest").canExecute());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("[ERROR]: LLVM failed to execute with error " + e.toString());

    }
}
```

When testing this function it outputs this exception:

```
LLVM failed to execute with error org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.nio.BufferOverflowException
```

Java version `graalvm-ce-11`

OS `Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon`

My llvm-bc file is 87.8 KB large (is it simply too large for the evaluation process?).

Any help or suggestions are appreciated :).